# Automating CSV file merging and cleaning

Tags: csv, powershell, batch-file, merge

I'm not a code guy and have spent whole day trying to get this done without success, hoping I can get some help from the experts.

I have a folder called Vehicles, within which are two sub-folders - Automobiles and Trucks. Each of sub-folders contain two CSV files which have identical (to that sub-folder) headers/structure.
What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Take the two CSV files in Automobiles folder merge them without duplicating headers and name the merged file as Automobiles.csv
2. Delete all rows in Automobiles.csv where 6th column (header is Fuel_Type) is "Diesel" (without the quotes) then move the file from sub-folder to main Vehicles folder.
3. Take the two CSV files in Trucks folder merge them without duplicating headers and name merge file as Trucks.csv
4. For merged file in trucks folder remove all rows where 6th column (header is "Fuel_Type") is "Diesel" (without the quotes) then move the file from sub-folder to main Vehicles folder.
   Obviously if someone can help with 1 and 2 I can manipulate it for 3 and 4.
5. BONUS POINTS :) take the Automobiles.csv and Trucks.csv files and create Vehicles.xls file with Automobiles and Trucks tabs.

Few details - files are pretty large, each CSV can up to 350 thousand rows x 150 columns and be 200 MB in size each. All the Batch scripts that I tried to put together removing headers seemed to freeze with larger files.

Due to user permissions  on work computers would strongly prefer to use something that is native to Windows7/8 and doesn't require additional software, but would consider other options if nothing native is available.

Comment: This seems like it would be better suited to a VBA Macro in Excel. One of our programmers where I work did something similar for me a few years ago because pure batch just does not handle this as good as other solutions.  Powershell probably handles it better then batch as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume all csv files contain the same header information, in the same order. This is how i would do it in powershell v2:

```
Function Merge-Vehicles 
{
param(
[string]$PathToCsv1,
[string]$PathToCsv2,
[string]$ExportPath
)   
$regex = "^(?:d|D)(?:i|I)(?:e|E)(?:s|S)(?:e|E)(?:l|L)$"
$CSV = Import-Csv $PathToCsv1
$CSV += Import-Csv $PathToCsv2
$CSV | Where-Object { ( $_.'Fuel_Type' -notmatch "$regex") } | Export-Csv -Path $ExportPath
}
```

First the function will import the csv files from a user defined path, and combine the imported objects into an array. It will than filter the objects that do not contain the string "Diesel" within the property 'Fuel_Type'. The objects that remain will be exported as a csv to a user defined path.

To call the function for Automobiles

```
Merge-Vehicles -PathToCsv1 C:\Vehicles\Autmobiles\csv1.csv -PathToCsv2 C:\Vehicles\Autmobiles\csv2.csv -ExportPath C:\Vehicles\Autmobiles.csv
```

And for Trucks

```
Merge-Vehicles -PathToCsv1 C:\Vehicles\Trucks\csv1.csv -PathToCsv2 C:\Vehicles\Trucks\csv2.csv -ExportPath C:\Vehicles\Trucks.csv
```

I don't have excel installed so I can't help with the workbook creation.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\vehicles\automobiles"
SET "destdir=U:\vehicles"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\file1.csv" "%sourcedir%\file2.csv") DO (
 ECHO(%%a>"%destdir%\vehicles.csv"
 ECHO(%%a>"%destdir%\vehicles_censored.csv"
 GOTO donehdrs
)
:donehdrs
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1-6*usebackqdelims=," %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\file1.csv" "%sourcedir%\file2.csv") DO (
 ECHO(%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g>>"%destdir%\vehicles.csv"
 IF "%%f" neq "Diesel" ECHO(%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g>>"%destdir%\vehicles_censored.csv"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You don't really indicate whether you want the intermediate files.

Note that this will **not** work properly if any field before field 6 contains a "quoted string containing commas" nor if any field before field 6 is **completely** empty (ie. on lines of the form `data1,data2,,data4,data5,data6,data7`)

Insufficient info to improve without examining a plethora of possibilities...

Answer (score 0):

It might even be easier to simply use `copy` to merge the two files, then use an editor to remove the superfluous header line.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are inherently slow, and this is evident when large data files are processed. I think the method below is the fastest way to perform this process using a Batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd C:\Vehicles
call :MergeFiles Automobiles > Automobiles.csv
call :MergeFiles Trucks > Trucks.csv
goto :EOF


:MergeFiles

rem Enter to the given sub-folder (Automobiles or Trucks)
pushd %1

rem Process the (two) CSV files existent here
set "keepHeader=1"
for %%f in (*.csv) do (
   ECHO Procesing file: "%%~Ff" > CON
   call :ProcessFile < "%%f"
   set "keepHeader="
)

popd
exit /B


:ProcessFile

set /P "line="
if defined keepHeader echo(!line!

SET LINES=0

rem Reset errorlevel
ver > NUL
:loop
   set /P "line="
   if errorlevel 1 exit /B
   for /F "tokens=6 delims=," %%a in ("!line!") do (
      if "%%a" neq "Diesel" echo(!line!
   )

   REM Optional part: show progress
   SET /A "LINES+=1, MOD100=LINES%%100"
   IF %MOD100% EQU 0 ECHO Lines processed: %LINES% > CON

goto loop
```

Note: this method fail if input lines are larger than 1023 characters, but accordingly to your data (350 thousand rows in a file 200 MB in size) each row have 600 bytes approx.